# GKE: ingres with sub-domain

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress

I used to work with Openshift/OKD cluster deployed in AWS and there it was possible to connect cluster to some domain name from Route53. Then as soon as I was deploying ingress with some hosts mappings (and the hosts defined in ingres were subdomains of the basis domain) all necessary lb rules (Routes in Openshift) and subdomain itself were created by Openshift and were directly available. For example: Openshift is connected to domain "somedomain.com" which is registered in Route53. In ingress I have the host mapping like:

```
  hosts:
    - host: sub1.somedomain.com
      paths:
        - path
```

After deployment I can reach sub1.somedomain.com. Is this kind of functionality available in GKE?
So far I have seen only mapping to static IP.

Also I red here https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/ingress-http2 that if I need to connect service with ingress, the service have to be of type NodePort. Is it realy so? In Openshift it was not required any normal ClusterIP service could be connected to ingress.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far GKE does not provide the possibility to dynamically create subdomains. The wished situation would be if GKE cluster can be set some DNS zone managed in GCP and there is a mimik of OpenShift Routes using for example ingress annotations.

But the reality tight now - you have to create subdomain or domain youself as well as IP address wich you connect this domain to. And this particular GCP IP address (using name) can be connected to ingress using annotations. Or it can be used in loadbalancer service.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should consider the other [Ingress Controllers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress-controllers/) for your use cases.

I'm not an expert of the GKE, but as I can see [Best practices for enterprise multi-tenancy](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/best-practices/enterprise-multitenancy#load-balancing) as follows,
you need to consider how to route the multiple Ingress hostnames through wildcard subdomain like the OpenShift additionally.

```
Set up HTTP(S) Load Balancing with Ingress
:
You can create and configure an HTTP(S) load balancer by creating a Kubernetes Ingress resource, 
which defines how traffic reaches your Services and how the traffic is routed to your tenant's application. 
By registering Services with the Ingress resource, the Services' naming convention becomes consistent, 
showing a single ingress, such as tenanta.example.com and tenantb.example.com.
```

The routing feature depends on the [Ingress Controllers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress-controllers/) basically.
In my finding, the default Ingress Controllers of the GKE just creates a Google Cloud HTTP(S) Load Balancer, but it does not consider multi-tenancy by default like the OpenShift.

In contrast, in the OpenShift, the Ingress Controller was implemented using HAProxy with dynamic configuration feature as follows.

```
LB -tenanta.example.com--> HAProxy(directly forward the tenanta.example.com traffic to the target pod IPs) ---> Target Pods
```

Answer (score 1):

The type of service exposition depends on the K8S implementation on each cloud provider.

- If the ingress controller is a component inside  your cluster, a ClusterIP is enough to have your service reachable (internally from inside the cluster itself)
- If the ingress definition configure an external element (in case of GKE, a load balancer), this element isn't a part of the cluster and can't know the ClusterIP (because it is only accessible internally). A node port is required in this case.

So, in your case, either you expose your service in NodePort, or you configure GKE with another Ingress controller, locally installed in the cluster, instead of using this one by default.